# Backbone, setting el for subview when parent view is not in DOM?

Tags: backbone.js, view

I used to use `mySubView = new Backbone.View({el: 'my-class'})`

This worked great when I had my parent view attached to the DOM.

When parent view is not attached to the DOM, I can't use the `el` to specify where I want the subview appear.

How should I specify the el property of subview(specify where subview should attach itself to) when parent-view is not yet attached to DOM?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when you do `mySubView = new Backbone.View({el: 'my-class'})`, you are in the context of a view already.

If you don't specify an `el` to a Backbone View, it creates one (see [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/53f77901a4ea9c7cf75d3db93ddddf491998d90f/backbone.js#L1100)). After rendering your view, you can access the element and append it wherever you want. In your case:

```
var mySubView = new Backbone.View();

mySubView.render();

this.$('my-class').html(mySubView.el);
```

Comment: ah yes, simple! Do you see any difference with `this.subview.setElement(this.$('.my-class')).render();` as in http://ianstormtaylor.com/rendering-views-in-backbonejs-isnt-always-simple/ As a matter of fact, I haven't seen example code like yours yet even though it looks so natural.

Comment: I guess I found why your style is not used. when subview is updated, the DOM can't be updated because of the `html()` subview 's html is rendered and used once, but there's no connection between the DOM and the subview.

Comment: What do you mean "when subview is updated"? Here is an example of what I did. http://jsfiddle.net/GWNd2/1/